# Android: Handling touch events in the child, with parent sending (OnTouchListener)

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

In the child object, we need to track the coordinates (ACTION_MOVE).  If the coordinates `getX() > x`, we must send event to the parent object.

Problem: To send the event to the parent we need to return false, but if false is returned, we will not be able to track the coordinates of the object in the child.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v,MotionEvent e) {
    if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        if (e.getY() > 200) {
            return false;  //we must send event to the parent object, but since then the ACTION_MOVE event no longer occurs here
        } else {
            myView.setTranslationY(e.getY());
            return true;   //we have to handle the event here
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

What can I do to handle both conditions properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define an interface in the child class and it would be implemented by the parent. When you need to send the event to the parent object, you call the interface method, something like this:

Child class:

```
     public boolean onTouch(View v,MotionEvent e){
    if(e.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
        if(e.getY()>200){
           super.onTouchChildListener(v,e);
         }else{
          myView.setTranslationY(e.getY());
         }
          return true;
    }
    return false;
}

...

 public interface OnChildListener {
    void onTouchChildListener(View v, MotionEvent e);
}
```